# Checkbox inside Update Panel causing full post back

Tags: c#, asp.net, checkbox, updatepanel, postback

I have registration form for users to fill up. In there, one field is there to which if user checks on the button a text box shoulld be enabled to enter the number. I have used following code :

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="upMSME" runat="server">
        <ContentTemplate>
            <tr>
                <td colspan="2">
                    <asp:Label ID="lblMSME" runat="server" Text="Whether covered under MSME (Tick whichever is applicable)"></asp:Label>

                    <asp:CheckBox AutoPostBack="true" Checked="true" ID="chbMSME" runat="server" OnCheckedChanged="chbMSME_CheckedChanged" ClientIDMode="AutoID"/>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr id="trMSMENo" runat="server">
                <td>
                    <asp:Label ID="lblMSMENo" runat="server" Text="MSME Number" CssClass="alignTop"></asp:Label>
                </td>
                <td class="ValueBox">
                    <asp:TextBox ID="txtMSMENo" runat="server" MaxLength="75"></asp:TextBox>
                    <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="rfvMSMENo" runat="server" ForeColor="Red" ErrorMessage="*" ControlToValidate="txtMSMENo" ValidationGroup="vgVendor"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>

                </td>
            </tr>
        </ContentTemplate>
    </asp:UpdatePanel>
```

However I searched over internet and found that by setting the `ClientIDMode="AutoID"` the issue is resolved. But in my case after setting the property there is still full postback occurred.

I have another update panel  also in this form, does it make any difference?
What am I missing?

Comment: What do you mean with _full postback_? Does you notice any flickering, does the page jump to the top or do you just mean that `Page_Load` gets called on the server which is normal?

Comment: I have a field for the uploading a file, on top of that field. After checking/unchecking, the file upload control loses the value. I have another update panel in same form, does it make any difference?

Comment: The file-upload control doesn't work in asynchronous postbacks anyway. I suggest to read this article: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/482800/FileplusUploadplusinplusUpdateplusPanel

Comment: I just explained that how I came to know about the full post back. But the update panel for another control works perfectly. i.e, it is not losing the data.

Comment: Post Your All code Behind Code and also OnCheckedChanged Code..!!

Comment: Put updatemode=conditional and set asynctrigger for checkbox and see if its getting fired. and as a last resort  try removing styling inside update panel and see if that helps.